# AB=AC=I $\rightarrow$ B=C

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let there be $A \in F^{n*n}$

If $AB=AC=I \rightarrow B=C$

Because we know that every matrix have one rref (Reduced row echelon form) that mean that B and C are group of elementary actions, and due to the uniqueness of the rref of $A$ they must be the same elementary actions, therefore $B=C$

am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$AB=AC=I$ means $B$ and $C$ are the inverse of $A$. By the uniqueness of inverse, $B=C$.

Comment: The main difficulty of the proof is hidden in the first sentence.

Answer (score 4):

The main non-trivial question here seems to be whether $A$ is invertible. It actually is and here is an easy proof of that: $$1=\det I=\det(AB)=(\det A)(\det B).$$ In particular, $\det A\neq 0$, which is equivalent to the existence of $A^{-1}$.

Now, pre-multiply $AB=AC\,(\,=I)$ by $A^{-1}$ to conclude that $B=C\,(\,=A^{-1})$.

Answer (score 3):

In general, thinking in terms of rref is a useful strategy, but I'm skeptical of attempting to do this here. A prior, a sequence of row operations putting $B$ into rref may not also put $C$ into rref. I'm also not sure what you mean by "the same elementary actions".

**Hint:** Recall that the ring of $n \times n$ matrices is isomorphic to the ring of linear maps from $F^n$ to $F^n$. If we let $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal B$, $\mathcal C$, and $\mathcal I$ be the linear maps represented by $A$, $B$,$C$, and $I$, respectively, it's enough to show that $\mathcal A \circ \mathcal B = \mathcal A \circ \mathcal C \implies \mathcal B= \mathcal C$.

First, try to prove that $\mathcal A$ is a linear isomorphism, and therefore has two-sided inverse, $\mathcal D$. For this, note that $\mathcal A$ is surjective under our hypotheses, since $\mathcal B$ is a right inverse. Now apply the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) to show $\mathcal A$ is surjective as well. It follows that there exists some $\mathcal D$ so that $\mathcal D \mathcal \circ A = \mathcal I$. Do you see how to show that $\mathcal B= \mathcal C$ now?

Comment: Though this is useful, I think a user asking a question about RREF and existence of inverses wont be familiar with ring isomorphisms and linear maps and that this terminology is more likely to confuse rather than to help

Comment: @MSEoris, that's a valid objection. I hesitated to post this answer because that crossed my mind, but since they're working over a general field I was thinking they might have a little more background than the typical linear algebra student.

Comment: @MorganO I have yet to learn about rings, just starting linear mapping now

Comment: @gbox, I'm sorry if my answer caused confusion. You can replace the first sentence of my "hint" with the following: "Recall that, once a basis for $F^n$ is chosen, $n \times n$ matrices are in one-to-one correspondence with linear maps from $F^n$ to $F^n$. Moreover, under this identification, matrix multiplication corresponds to function composition, and the identity matrix corresponds to the identity map." The reason to bring up this identification in the first place is to be able to use familiar properties of functions in the proof.